# What is the origin of caricatured gangsters using "say?" to end sentences?

Tags: slang

Here's an example:

[image: 'As long as I count the Votes, what are you going to do about it? say?']

From [Harper's Weekly, 7 October 1871](https://www.masshist.org/database/viewer.php?item_id=5900&pid=41)

I also recall watching cartoon gangsters, from Looney Toons using this. For the longest time I thought they were saying "see?"

What is the origin of this postscript to gangster-spoken sentences?

Comment: "What say you?"

Comment: What makes you think this relates only to gangsters and cartoons?

Comment: Did I say this effect is only in gangsters and cartoons and not in anything else? Do I need to enumerate all other occurrences of this phenomenon before asking the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [OED](https://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/171590) (and you can see this page **for free**), this usage is "originally and chiefly N. American". The first quote it cites is in [Domestic Manners Of The Americans](https://archive.org/stream/domesticmannerso002427mbp#page/n343/mode/2up) (1832), which I think refers to this:

> What is it, man? say.

It can also start a sentence, as OED lists in subsequent entries:

> Say—d'you run with our machine?
> — Lantern (N.Y., 1852)

Here's another example from 1857:

> "Say! What are you laughing at? I only did it for fun."
> — [The Bay-path: A Tale of New England Colonial Life](https://archive.org/stream/baypathatalenew00hollgoog#page/n340/mode/2up)

However, I think the gangster association comes from the 1920s, based on this Huffington Post article:

> In the 1920s, gangsters like Jack McGurn - Al Capone’s main assassin and general of his troops - would begin many sentences with “Say.” For example: “Say, what’s the beef?” Or, “Say, I wasn’t anywhere near the place. See?” Say and see were like bookends to the street comment.
> — [Hipster Language: How To Talk Like A 20s Gangster](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/jeffrey-gusfield/gangster-language_b_1397951.html)

As you can see, you didn't mishear; gangsters also say "see". For example, in the 1931 movie *Little Caesar*: ["You're hangin' around with me, see?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Js6mgxdFLE4)

Comment: Logically, 'say' would be used with questions, and 'see' with declarations.

Comment: This answer does really not **explain** the **origin** of this usage (how it is related to the more central uses of *say*); it merely confirms that it has been around for some time.

Comment: The one quoted by the OP is really off. This answer is  how this "say" works. But at the end, it has to be written like this: "What you going to do about it, say?"