# What is the history of using the word "say" to start a sentence?

Tags: etymology, expressions

What is the history of using the word "say" to start a sentence?

An example is from Mark Twain, The Adventures of Tom Sawyer (1876)   -- "Oh, shucks, I'll be just as careful. Now lemme try. **Say**—I'll give you the core of my apple."

Comment: I think I already answered this [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/410319/191178); ironically the question asks about *say* ending a sentence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the origin of caricatured gangsters using "say?" to end sentences?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/410313/what-is-the-origin-of-caricatured-gangsters-using-say-to-end-sentences)

Comment: @Laurel - My gut feel is that "Say" starting a sentence is generally different in meaning and etymology from "say" ending a sentence.  The typical use of "say" ending a sentence is short for the rhetorical question "what say you".  "Say" starting a sentence is no doubt a shortened form of some expression, possibly along the lines of "What would you say if" (which does **not** mean the same as "what say you").

Comment: What's special about using the word *say* to start a sentence? *Suppose, Consider, What if, ...*.

Comment: The Germans also do this "Sag mal..." and this is cognate. The French do a similar thing "Dis donc, ...." which is _not_ cognate, but could be a loan translation. But either way the phenomenon is not restricted to English.

Comment: My cousin used to do that all the time. I think there is a difference between using say at the beginning and at the end of sentences. At the beginning, it is asking a question. At the end, it is making suggestion.

Comment: There is a very long history of using otherwise irrelevant words to start a sentence. From Beowulf's "hwaet" to todays' "So". This is probably just a filler to say, "I am about to say something so please listen" (otherwise the first word of the sentence might get lost).

Comment: Say Adam, where did you get that apple?

Answer (score -1):

Using an [ngram](/questions/tagged/ngram), we can compare the relative occurrence of *say* at the beginning and ending of sentences in books. According to [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_START_+say%2Csay+_END_&year_start=1500&year_end=1800&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C_START_%20say%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csay%20_END_%3B%2Cc0), the first usage of using *say* at the end of a sentence was around 1689. The first recorded use of *say* to begin a sentence, however, was much earlier, around 1560.

We can also see that there are a substantial (relative to the overall occurrence of say at the beginning and ending of sentences) number of sentences beginning with *say* even before the one ending with *say* is first observed. After that, the number of sentences starting with *say* seems to be much larger, relatively speaking. To observe that, I suggest looking at [this n-gram (1670 till 1800)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_START_+say%2Csay+_END_&year_start=1670&year_end=1800&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C_START_%20say%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csay%20_END_%3B%2Cc0).

I also looked at [the n-gram from 1600 till 1900 of the following words starting a sentence: say, suppose, consider, what and if](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_START_+say%2C_START_+suppose%2C_START_+consider%2C+_START_+what%2C_START_+if&year_start=1600&year_end=1900&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C_START_%20say%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_START_%20suppose%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_START_%20consider%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_START_%20what%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_START_%20if%3B%2Cc0), which shows that of those, *if* and *what* are used the most (by a lot).  [When removing those two](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_START_+say%2C_START_+suppose%2C_START_+consider&year_start=1600&year_end=1900&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C_START_%20say%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_START_%20suppose%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_START_%20consider%3B%2Cc0), the remaining three seem to occur in the same order of magnitude.

Regarding the actual texts in which those words occurred, that cannot be observed from the n-grams. Nevertheless, I hope the graphs offer some interesting perspective on the matter.

Comment: It is unfortunate that Ngram does not show the "hits", so we cannot evaluate the frequency of "Say, ..." vs "Say 'mother may I'".